# How to be certain "cp -n -r /dir/ /des/" does not overwrite files.. and is doing its job ? verbose mode?

Tags: cp, recursive

I run the command

```
 cp -n -r /dir/ /backup/
```

but there is no way to tell what it is doing.. 
if it is skipping files that already exists..

if it is doing anything..

I tried adding

```
-v
```

option to it.. still no data.. on what it is doing..

Comment: Are you using stdout/stderr redirection (`>`)? When I use `cp -v * Test` where Test is a directory the output is similar to `"oldfile.txt" -> "Test/oldfile.txt"`...

Comment: Are you adding the `-v` option before the `/dir/` and `/backup/` arguments like this: `cp -nrv /dir/ /backup/`?

Comment: try `rsync -av --ignore-existing /dir/ /backup/`